# DataTable.Select with DateTime stored as String

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, select, datatable

I have a `DataTable` with a `DateTime` stored as a `string` like "20.12.2017".
I want to select all rows within the last 6 month.

I can do this with a `foreach`:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsErgebnisse.Tables[0].Rows)
{
   if (Convert.ToDateTime(dr[6].ToString()) > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6))
   {
       dsTemp.Tables[0].ImportRow(dr);
   }
}
```

This gives me 3.613 rows.

I try to do this with a select to check if it's faster:

```
DataRow[] foundRows = dsErgebnisse.Tables[0].Select("DATUM > '" + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6).ToShortDateString() + "'");
```

`DATUM` is my column where the `DateTime`is stored as a string. 
This gives me 2.624 rows.

Why is there a difference?
I tried to use convert in the select statement but I fail with `System.Data.EvaluateException`:

```
foundRows = dsErgebnisse.Tables[0].Select("Convert(DATUM, 'System.DateTime') > '" + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6).ToShortDateString() + "'");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- rule 0: stop using `DataTable`... just ever*
- rule 1: don't store date/time values as strings; store them as `DateTime` or similar
- rule 2: if you ignore rules 0 and 1, make sure you store them in a sortable order like "2017-12-20"

since you've broken all of those rules, most bets are off, and you'll probably have to do the filter manually by iterating over the rows, fetching the values, and doing your own conversions. LINQ via `.AsEnumerable()` *may* help; it certainly can't make it much worse :)

---

*=there is a tiny category of problems where `DataTable` is appropriate; if you know the schema of the data in advance well enough to issue a `Select` query: this isn't one of them

Comment: Thanks for the answer